# Installing Python Module Error

Tags: python, windows

I'm a using Windows 7, Python 2.6. I've downloaded the Levenshtein extension from http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/downloads/detail?name=python-Levenshtein-0.10.1.tar.bz2&can=2&q=

I've set up the environment variables to C:\PYTHON26;C:\PYTHON26\DLLs;C:\PYTHON26\LIB;C:\PYTHON26\LIB\LIB-TK

When I run the python install setup.py to actually install it, I get:

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'Levenshtein' extension
error: None
```

Then I try to `import Levenshtein` 
and I get the `ImportError: No module named Levenshtein`

import StringMatcher yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
File "stringMatcher.py", line 1, in (module)
from Levenshtein imoprt *
ImportError: No module name Levenshtein
```

Am I missing something stupid? This seems to happen with every extra module that I try to install.

Comment: If anyone could provide any guesses, any info would be appreciated? I'm really stumped here.

Comment: what does it tells you if you try to `import StringMatcher` ?

Comment: I put the imoprt StringMatcher error into the code above. Thanks for your help

Comment: it seems that the "Levenshtein.so" library was not built. Did you run `python setup.py build` ? If yes, what was it's result in `build/lib.linux{your_arch}/` ?

Comment: I also have the same issue, but on windows XP

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it correctly, it should work by adding C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages to your python path

Comment: You mean to the Environment Variables? I added the above and it still errors out

Comment: Create another environment variable named PYTHONPATH and add your paths above plus the one I added. Try restarting before testing to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that your environment did not have paths to the c compiler. Levenshtein library is written in C and should be compiled using a c compiler.

I had the same problem, but resolved as described below.

Firstly, you should have Microsoft Visual Studio (for c compiler). I did never try other c compilers for windows.

Then do the below steps:

1. set path=C:\Python26\Scripts;C:\Python26;%path%
2. Just run: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat  (path varies according to your visual studio installed area). This is to set paths to MS VS.

   1. set VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\  (put your installed path to visual studio)
   2. python setup.py build (optionally you can use --compiler msvc, i.e. python setup.py build --compiler msvc)